# using output variable from one stage to another

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I am trying to call one template in azure pipelines based on condition but not able too. I tried multiple ways.

in my azure-pipelies.yml file I am calling multiple templates like below.
as part of my azure_ci_build_ABC.yml I am setting one output variable isTrue.

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isTrue;isOutput=true]${IS_TRUE}"
```

I am trying to get the value in if condition like below but not able too. Am i missing something.

```
stages:
  - template: templates/azure_ci_build_ABC.yml
  - template: templates/azure_ci_build_DEF.yml
  - ${{ if eq(($[stageDependencies.stage_get_version.job_get_version.outputs['step_version_setup.isTrue']], 'false')) }}:
     - template: templates/azure_ci_build_MNC.yml
```

How can we access the isTrue variable in if condition if i wanted.

Comment: may i know if there's any update? You can follow the reply below for  a check, let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can we access the isTrue variable in if condition if i wanted.

You cannot do this. The `if expression` is expanded at `compile time`, while the setvariable is running at `runtime` which is after. Hence if expression cannot parse the variable value.

For example, below yaml `works`, since the predefined variable `Build.SourceBranch` can be parsed at compile time.

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: stageA
  jobs:
  - job: job1
    steps:
      - script: echo stage A

- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main') }}: 
  - stage: stageB
    jobs: 
    - job: job2
      steps:
        - script: run stage B conditionally
```

Typically, we can use `condition` instead of `if expression` as it can get the runtime variable value. But since you are using `template`, you cannot simply replace the if expression with `condition`, you need to set `condition` **in** the template yaml not above it.

You can use below:

The main yaml, remove if expression as it cannot be parsed.

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - template: templates/azure_ci_build_ABC.yml
  - template: templates/azure_ci_build_DEF.yml
  - template: templates/azure_ci_build_MNC.yml
```

The templates\azure_ci_build_ABC.yml:

```
stages:
- stage: stage_get_version
  jobs:
  - job: job_get_version
    steps:
    - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isTrue;isOutput=true]false"
      name: step_version_setup
```

To use the variable in the `templates\azure_ci_build_MNC.yml`, you need to set `dependencies` in condition, you can check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65219288/14996050) for your reference.

Please notice the comment in the yaml:

```
stages:
- stage: stage_MNC
  dependsOn: 
  - stage_get_version
  - StageDEF
  condition: eq(dependencies.stage_get_version.outputs['job_get_version.step_version_setup.isTrue'], 'false')    # notice here you need to use dependencies
  variables:
    varFromA: $[ stageDependencies.stage_get_version.job_get_version.outputs['step_version_setup.isTrue'] ]     # notice here you need to use stageDependencies
  jobs:
  - job: checkresult
    steps:
    - bash: echo test $(varFromA)
```

The execution result:

[image]